# What code can I use to put the pdf link in google sheet using app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this existing code that I use in google sheet that whenever I run the script, the paychecks would automatically convert to pdf and will have its own folder. Now, I want to add the link of the pdf inside the google sheet but I don't know what code should I add into it. Below is my existing code that I use in my google sheet.

```
function finishedPayslip(){
  makePDF()
  mnthly()
  clearPayslipFields()
}

function makePDF() {
  
  // Get the currently active spreadsheet URL (link)
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Paycheck");

  //Creating an exportable URL
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?".replace("SS_ID", ss.getId());
  var folderID = "1A691O2hh96wlKWDuZ-P9S9CK_MDTAWcm"; // Folder id to save in a folder.
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var employeeName = ss.getRange("'Paycheck'!C4").getValue()
  var pdfName = employeeName;

  /* Specify PDF export parameters
  From: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3579
  */
  var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'        // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
  + '&size=letter'                       // paper size legal / letter / A4
  + '&portrait=true'                    // orientation, false for landscape
  + '&fitw=true&source=labnol'           // fit to page width, false for actual size
  + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
  + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
  + '&fzr=false'                         // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  + '&gid=';                             // the sheet's Id
    
  // Convert individual worksheet to PDF
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + sheet.getSheetId(), {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
    }
  });
  

var blobs = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName + '.pdf');


var folders = folder.getFoldersByName(pdfName);
folder = folders.hasNext() ? folders.next() : folder.createFolder(pdfName);


var newFile = folder.createFile(blobs);
  
  // Define the scope
  Logger.log("Storage Space used: " + DriveApp.getStorageUsed());

}
```

The output will be like I will add an another column at the end of my sheet named "pdf link" and the links for pdf per employee will appear inside my google sheet. What code should I add?

Additional information: My sheet looks like I have a template generator or paycheck generator inside my sheet, and whenever I run the script, it would automatically go to their designated sheet since it is separated by period (January, February and so on)

Thank you!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. In your goal, where do you want to put the `pdf link`? I couldn't understand `an another column at the end of my sheet named "pdf link"`. And about `Additional information:`, I cannot understand it. Can I ask you about the detail of `Additional information:`?

Comment: @Tanaike Hi! No worries. I would like to put the pdf file inside my google sheet. So that I'll have an access on it.

Sharing here is my sample link 
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xKfNqOKbLTWuoRK8WxrhrIt9qlI6f5Fc?usp=sharing

On that folder "sample", there is another folder there named "paychecks" that is where all the pdf file generated from paychecks generator. What I need to do is to put the link of the pdf file inside my paycheck generator google sheet. You might want to check the link, I made a sample on January sheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike No worries. I am generating paychecks for employees. Whenever I run the script, the pdf for their paychecks will be generated in their folder. I would like to get that link of pdf and put it inside the google sheet. Inside the google sheet, there are sheets named Jan, Feb, etc.

Ex. 
I have generated a paycheck for Smith at the month of January. Once I run the script, there will a pdf file for smith and on the January sheet, Smith's name will appear there. And after the "remaining" column at January on Smith's name, I would like the link of the pdf of Smith will appear there.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to create a PDF file and retrieve the URL of the PDF file, and want to put the URL to the column "S".
- In this case, the sheet name is retrieved from the cell `'Paycheck'!H3`. And, you want to search the name from the column "A" of the sheet and put the URL to the column "S" of the same row.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var newFile = folder.createFile(blobs);
```

#### To:

```
var newFile = folder.createFile(blobs);
var sheetName = ss.getRange("'Paycheck'!H3").getValue();
var range = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName).getRange("A2:A").createTextFinder(employeeName).findNext();
if (range) {
  range.offset(0, 18).setValue(newFile.getUrl());
}
```

In this modified script, the sheet name is retrieved from the cell `'Paycheck'!H3` and the row is searched by TextFinder, and the URL is put to the column "S" of the searched row.

#### Reference:

- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)